# How can I get rid of Activities in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I'm currently visiting a foreign university, where I'm using an Ubuntu system. The Desktop has something in the upper-left corner called Activities. I have to click it or mouse through it to do most little tasks involving starting or switching between applications. I find it disagreeable because what takes a single click in most Desktops requires three or more clicks with Activities, and I have to go through menus and animations of sliding and swirling windows in order to find what I'm looking for, which I find disorienting. Workspaces get auto-deleted if they go for a moment without any windows in them, etc. I've been struggling with it for two weeks now, and I no longer believe that I'll get used to it.

I understand that Linux is very good for customization and configurability. How can I set up a simpler, more-efficient Desktop? I don't know their names, but I've used other Desktops on Linux that do nice things like put all running applications on a "task bar" so you can reach them in a single click, all workspaces stable and accessible on the task bar, handy gadgets that you can add to the task bar to display stuff like CPU and network usage, etc. I think this used to be called GNOME, but the thing with Activities also appears to be called GNOME.

Here is the contents of `/proc/version`:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-59-generic (buildd@lgw01-43) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #98-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:05:26 UTC 2015
```

I don't have root access.    ￼

Answer (score 2):

I take it you are using GNOME then.It's pretty simple to optimize GNOME for Desktop usage.First go to their extensions site which is https://extensions.gnome.org

In there download and install the following:

- Applications Menu
- Dash to dock
- User Themes
- AlternateTab
- Caffeine

After installing all those extensions you should be able to use GNOME efficiently.

Comment: Thanks! I have just successfully downloaded and installed several of the extensions. Some seem to work, though, and some don't. For example, "Dash to Dock" seems to have no effect (even after rebooting). How could I diagnose problems? Or rather, can you point me to some sort of documentation that would enable me to see what's going on? (So far, I haven't found anything useful [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-overview.html.en ).

Comment: You can enable and disable extensions with the GNOME Tweak Tool.Just type the Super Key(Your Windows Key) and search for Tweak Tool.In it go to the Extensions tab and from there you should be able to enable Dash To Dock.

Comment: Thanks again! It turned out that "Dash to Dock" was already working; I expected it to do something different. The extension I needed to turn on was "Window list" (already installed, actually). "Systemmonitor" didn't work on this machine, but I installed an excellent one, "System-monitor", which is downright beautiful.